# Oracle - Execute several sql files in a transaction

Tags: oracle

I have several sql files. I need to execute them in a transaction. When an error occurs all changes will be rolled back.

Is this possible using sqlplus or some other tool ?

EDIT There are not any explicit commits in those files, just DDL sql.

Comment: If there are no implicit commits (e.g. data definition statements) involved, just concat all source files into a bigger one.

Comment: you don't provide any details... but generally: whether this is possible depends extremely on the content of the SQL files (for example are there explicit `COMMIT`s ? Are any Stored Procedure involved ? Are there any DDL commands ? Are any DB Links involved ? etc.)... if you don't know/have control over the content of the SQL files I would say no...

Comment: Thanks for the EDIT... please see my answer below...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally: whether this is possible depends extremely on the content of the SQL files - for example:

- are there explicit `COMMIT`s ?
- are any Stored Procedures involved ?
- are there any DDL commands ?
- are any DB Links involved ?

etc.

IF you don't know/have control over the content of the SQL files I would say no..

IF you can make sure that the files don't contain any `COMMIT`, any DDL, any Stored Procedure calls etc. THEN you could just concatenate them and execute them in one transaction... how to do that exactly depends on your tool...

**UPDATE - after the OP added that the SQL files contain DDL command:**

The answer is NO since DDL commands use implicit `COMMIT` - although some DBs might allow for some "workaround" (for example Oracle has a configurable "Flashback-Area" which could be "abused" to achieve what you want) but most don't.

The usual way to solve this (DDL scripts / transactions) is to write 2 scripts - one to make all changes... and a second one to run only if an error occurred while executing the first one... how exactly to write such scripts depends on the specifics of your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [start](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve044.htm#i2699582) command, and the [whenever sqlerror](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve052.htm#i2700066) then just don't commit.

Comment: that won't work reliably if the SQL files contain `COMMIT` themselves and/or DDL commands and/or use DB Links and/or use Stored Procedures etc.

Comment: I meant implicit commits too, that's too obvious. Don't make a simple question become a trivial one!!

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, every DDL (Data Definition Language) command such as CREATE..., ALTER... or DROP... implicitly commits before and after the statement. So since your SQL files contain such statements, you cannot have a single transaction for them all.

This is not a limitation of using several files. It's a limitation of all Oracle DDL statements.

Comment: you are correct! one addition: in case of Oracle you could abuse the flashback area to rollback any and everything to a specific point in time (NOT RECOMMENDED!).